# Angular 2 Subscribe using arrow functions vs named function variables using bind

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When subscribing to Http Observable objects most tutorials use arrow functions :

```
this.myService.getItems.subscribe(
(data) => // do something,
(errors) => //handle errors);
```

Why don't use function variables instead to have cleaner code :

```
this.myService.getItems.subscribe(this.extractData.bind(this), this.handleErrors.bind(this));
```

Comment: `this.function.bind(this)` is _cleaner_? I disagree.

Comment: yes it is when it comes to embedded arrow functions of +10 lines

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your style. Using `(data) => { do something}` looks a bit confuse first time, but the more you use it, the more you are comfortable. You'll like it and don't want to use `this.extractData.bind(this)`